# Humidity sensor with more probes

Tags: arduino, sensor, humidity

Could you advice how to amend such schema in order to measure humidity on more probes?

[image]

The 555 is functioning as a resistance-to-frequency converter. A probe (on the left side of schema) is basically two wires. A resistance between them is converted into frequency (on the right side of diagram - green and white wire).

My idea is to have one NE555 and some sort of switch with every x seconds switch to another probe. The sensor is connected with Arduino, so Arduino can provide a clock on one output. I believe that then I don't need to have one dedicated Arduino input per probe. Just 1 input where frequency is read and one synchronization output.

How to achieve it? Or is there a better way how to deal with it?

Thanks, Tomas

Comment: What kind of sensor is that? All I see is a 555 circuit, no mention of what the sensor might be, nor how it's connected to the Arduino to read the sensed value.  More detail please.

Comment: @Majenko: The sensor is on the far left side of the diagram, shown as a resistance.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, I get that, but that doesn't explain what the sensor is. That's obviously an excitement circuit of some form, probably to feed a square wave into an reactive sensor, but I don't see where the Arduino fits into it. Normally I'd just drive those direct from 2 IO pins with a resistor, and an analog pin to read the voltage at the divider junction. I don't see where the analog input to the Arudino is there.

Comment: There is no analog input. The 555 is functioning as a resistance-to-frequency converter, and the Arduino reads the frequency at its output. In this case, the DISCH pin is being used as an open-collector output to the microcontroller.

Comment: @Majenko: I personally would guess its just two wires you stick into the earth. But then again, I guess it makes no sense to have the 555 circuit between the sensor and a µc. But I guess the OP has a reason he dos it that way. Perhaps he guessed that it was necessary. I guess.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Well, without actually knowing, we can't tell. It may be two probes for soil moisture content, or it may be an actual humidity sensor for airborne humidity.  All seems a bit odd and strange to me.

Comment: Ok, so it's basically just two wires. So why bother with the whole 555 circuit? It's not needed - you're just measuring resistance.

Comment: @Majenko: I updated my question with short explanation what circuit does. 
The benefit of this circuit compared to direct measurement of resistance is that via probe flowing AC current. So ions in soil are not polarized.

Comment: @Samot The same can be done direct by the Arduino - two output ports alternating between HIGH/LOW and LOW/HIGH with a resistor on one of them to the probe. Measure the voltage between the resistor and the probe. A simple analog MUX can then give you lots of probes.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a clock and counter you could use three digital Arduino pins to address a 74HC4051 analog multiplexer (total 4 pins required rather than 3) in order to select the oscillator output. You would also need one pull-up resistor on the Arduino input (frequency mode). This would allow up to 8 sensors with just two parts.

This scheme will work in either voltage or frequency mode, except that you'd need a single analog input rather than digital input for voltage mode and an electrolytic capacitor per sensor.

Answer (score 0):

To do the switching and keep track of the sensors, at the data end you'll need a clock pulse and an indexing pulse from the arduino.

At the sensor end you'll need something like a CD4017 counter driving something like CD4066 analog switches to select the various sensors.

You'll use the indexing pulse as a Master Reset (MR) for the counter / counter chain, and you'll clear a "sensor register" you've set up in the arduino to keep track of which sensor is being read. That way the Arduino will know, at the start, that it's reading sensor zero. To read sensor 1, the arduino will increment the sensor register and send a clock to the counter.  That clock will increment the counter, which will disconnect sensor zero from, and connect sensor 1 to the 2.2\$ \mu \$F capacitors.

Except for the MR part, the cycle will repeat for the rest of the sensors, and when it comes time to switch to sensor\$ \ 0 \$ again, the entire sequence will repeat, including the MR, just to make sure to get the train back on track in case it got derailed somewhere down the line.

BTW, do you need a way to turn on the sprinklers?

BTW BTW, what can you tell us about the wiring on the sensor end of the system and the resistance and resistance range(s) of the sensors?